# java regex extract numbers with boundary and optional space

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract 12 and 15.

```
AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF
.*\bAB CD\b\s?(\d+)\s?\bABC\b[/](\d+)\s?\bDEF\b
```

It is not working as i am not sure how to match exact words. I am trying to match exact words using boundary and it seems to be creating a problem.

I tried

```
.*\\bAB CD\\b\\s?(\\d+)\\s?\\bABC\\b[/](\\d+)\\s?\\bDEF\\b
.*\\bAB CD\\b\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\bABC\\b[/](\\d+)\\s*\\bDEF\\b
.*\\bAB CD\\b[\\s]?(\\d+)[\\s]?\\bABC\\b[/](\\d+)[\\s]?\\bDEF\\b
.*\\bAB CD\\b[\\s]*(\\d+)[\\s]*\\bABC\\b[/](\\d+)[\\s]*\\bDEF\\b
```

thanks.

Comment: Are all of your backslashes escaped (doubled) in your Java string literal?

Comment: Try `.*\bAB\sCD\s?(\d+)\s?ABC\/(\d+)\s?DEF\b`

Comment: Thos word boundaries are useless thhere.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the expression being a little redundant, you must be doing something wrong, as your very first expression works:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
 
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        
        String currentLine = "AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF";
        System.out.println("Current Line: "+ currentLine);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\bAB CD\\b\\s?(\\d+)\\s?\\bABC\\b[/](\\d+)\\s?\\bDEF\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(currentLine);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Matched: "+m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Matched: "+m.group(2));
        }
        
    }
}
```

And a demo link to prove: http://ideone.com/0tXFNu

Output:

```
Current Line: AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF
Matched: 12
Matched: 15
```

So make sure you use `m.group(NUMBER)` to access each of the matched values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
"AB\\s*CD\\s*(\\d+)\\s*ABC/(\\d+)\\s*DEF"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just extract digits out of string, try following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

If you want string match exactly except digits:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("AB\\s+CD\\s+(\\d+)\\s+ABC/(\\d+)\\s*DEF");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AB CD 12 ABC/15 DEF");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\bAB CD\b\s?(\d+)\s?\bABC\b[/](\d+)\s?\bDEF\b
                           ^^^        ^^ you dont need these \b
```